# Existence of double and repeated integrals

Tags: calculus

A double integral (such as $\int\int_{X\times Y}f(z)dz$) and a repeated integral (such as $\int_a^b\int_c^df(x,y)dxdy$) are two closely related concepts. I know that if s double integral exists then the corresponding repeated integrals exists and they are equal. Is the reverse true as well?

Comment: What do you mean by a "repeated integral" vs. a "double integral"?

Comment: Voting to close because this isn't a question

Comment: Sorry but didn't get it.i didn't write double vs repeated integral. I asked about their interdependence.

Comment: I've reworded the question for clarity. Have I made any undesirable changes?

Comment: Thanks stella for doing this im very new to do all this so sorry for my mistake. However this is my question. Thanks again.

Comment: The reverse is not always true. See Fubini's theorem and the typical counterexamples that  come with it.

Comment: Ok thanks sashi and stella. This really helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true in general. The correct version of this is called [Fubini's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and it requires additional assumptions. The linked wikipedia article contains several counterexamples when the assumptions are omitted.